# multiple keyword search in R stats

Tags: r

I have three sentence 
1) The fridge is broken for a month. 
2) The fridge is broken in 3 parts.
3) A broken fridge is of no use.

How can I use str_match in R so that I can use logical AND operator. So that it will search for both fridge and broken as keywords before returning the result.

The code that i used

```
x<- which(!is.na(str_match(data1$TWEET_TEXT,"fridge & broken")))
data9<- data1[x,]
```

But it is not working.
Can you please help as i am very new in R coding.

Comment: It should select only those sentences which have fridge and broken both as keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a vector of words ("v1") that needs to be detected, loop the vector using `lapply`, check whether the word is present in the "TWEET_TEXT" column (`grepl(x,..)`), use `Reduce` with `&`.  If the corresponding elements in the list are all TRUEs, the `&` will return "TRUE" or else "FALSE".  Using this as an index, the "data1" can be subsetted.

```
v1 <- c('broken', 'fridge') 
x1 <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(c('broken', 'fridge'),
                function(x) grepl(x, data1$TWEET_TEXT)))

data1[x1,, drop=FALSE]
#                          TWEET_TEXT
#1 The fridge is broken for a month.
#2   The fridge is broken in 3 parts
#3      A broken fridge is of no use
```

Another option would be to use `str_detect` from `stringr` or `stri_detect` from `stringi`.  If there are only two words, the below code should work too

```
library(stringr)
x2 <- with(data1, str_detect(TWEET_TEXT, 'broken') &
                           str_detect(TWEET_TEXT, 'fridge'))
data1[x2,, drop=FALSE]
```

#### data

```
data1 <-  structure(list(TWEET_TEXT = c("The fridge is broken for a month.", 
"The fridge is broken in 3 parts", "A broken fridge is of no use", 
"No use of fridge")), .Names = "TWEET_TEXT", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```